# How to upload file in chunks using Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I need to upload a file in 3 chunks (as an example), that I receive at different times of program execution.

Google Cloud Storage SDK provides [`upload`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload) method that has `resumable` and `offset` properties. I expect that I should be able to do:

```js
await googleStorageBucket.upload(chunk1, {
    destination: 'images/foo',
    gzip: false,
    offset: 0,
    predefinedAcl: 'publicRead',
    resumable: true,
    validation: 'md5',
});

await googleStorageBucket.upload(chunk2, {
    destination: 'images/foo',
    gzip: false,
    offset: 500,
    predefinedAcl: 'publicRead',
    resumable: true,
    validation: 'md5',
});

await googleStorageBucket.upload(chunk3, {
    destination: 'images/foo',
    gzip: false,
    offset: 1000,
    predefinedAcl: 'publicRead',
    resumable: true,
    validation: 'md5',
});
```

I expect that `chunk1`, `chunk2` and `chunk3` in this example are going to be concatenated to the same file, but instead the final file is only `chunk3`.

How does one use Google Cloud Storage SDK to upload file in chunks?

Comment: It looks like you need to use the uri option to continue a previously created resumable upload. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createResumableUpload

Comment: It doesn't look that way looking at the provided examples. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Click through to UploadOptions documentation and read about the uri option.

Comment: I still cannot figure it out. https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/3002

Comment: it seems you got a workaround in github.com. could you please post it here as an answer so the community can use it easily?

Comment: Because GCP imposes arbitrary restrictions on a chunk size, it is virtually impossible. There is no solution. What are you referring to?

Comment: If you are referring to their concatenation workaround, that would easily 10-100x the price of using their service. Not an option.

Comment: See https://github.com/googleapis/gcs-resumable-upload/issues/132#issuecomment-603493772 regarding price.